# Laravel 5 localization based on sub domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I have localization based on the subdomain?

`www.example.com` ==> locale = default local  = `en`
`ar.example.com` ==> local  = `ar`

After researching online, I am not sure if it should be a `middleware` or in the `routes` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{lang}.myapp.com'], function()
{

    Route::get('/', function($lang)
    {
        App::setLocale($lang);
    });

});
```

Or use the `App::setLocale` in your controller.

The group allows you to use a wildcard, `ar.example.com` `en.example.com` or `it.example.com` all will be catch by the group. Inside de group you can define all the routes you need and pass the `$lang`

Maybe you can add a `middleware` to limit the language, maybe a `middleware` that check if the language exists.

Comment: In which controller? All the website needs to have localization support.
If I use this Route group, should I duplicate all my routes to work for `en` and `ar`?

Comment: No, the group allows you to use a wildcard, `ar.example.com` `en.example.com` or `it.example.com`` all will be catch by the group.
Inside de group you can define all the routes you need and pass the $lang variable in the controller you need

Comment: Then wouldn't it make sense to make in a `middleware`?

Comment: I don't think so, if I where you I will use that method, maybe wait for other answers.

Comment: Maybe you can add a middleware to limit the language, maybe a middleware that check if the language exists

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. Thank you.
Can you update your answer so I can accept it?